# $safeprojectname$ isn't safe within the IWizard.RunStarted method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I've implemented the [IWizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.aspx) interface and I want to get `$safeprojectname$`. So, I use the following code:

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams) {
    var safeProjectName = replacementsDictionary["$safeprojectname$"];
}
```

But in this case `safeProjectName` is a string that contains spec symbols like `-`, `+` etc. For example, if a user set project name as `My-Project-1` `$safeprojectname$` will be `My-Project-1`. I expect `My_Project_1`.

Should I replace all unsafe symbols manually?

According this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx) it should work without any manipulation, but it doesn't:

> safeitemname - The name provided by the user in the Add New Item dialog box, with all unsafe characters and spaces removed.

PS:

Reproduces in VS Professional 2015 and VS Professional 2017.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, is a user set project name as My-Project-1 $safeprojectname$ will be My-Project-1. I expect My_Project_1.

You could replace '-' to '_', like this:

```
 var safeProjectName = replacementsDictionary["$safeprojectname$"];

 replacementsDictionary["$safeprojectname$"] = replacementsDictionary ["$safeprojectname$"].Replace("-", "_");
```